# How to open a url using javascript and set custom HTTP headers to the request?

Tags: javascript, cookies, http-headers, redirect

I want to redirect a user to a url through javascript after they click on a link. Now is there any way to send custom http headers along with this request. I want to send a particular cookie value with the request headers.

The url in question does not belong to my domain.

Is it possible to do it? If yes, how?

Comment: So you want to set a cookie for a different website? AFAIK, not possible.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Yes I realised, its essentially setting cookie for a different domain, which can never be possible (thank gods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You can set custom headers if you are using XMLHttpRequest (although it might ban you from setting a `Cookie` header), but not otherwise (and a redirect is otherwise).

Comment: Yes its not possible. And XMLHttpRequest will not work for me as it sends and receives data behind the scenes.