# How to move to another page using Javascript and access token?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0

This problem must have been solved billions of times, yet I'm having a hard time finding my way. I have a backend service that grants OAuth2 tokens with user/password. When the user logs in, I would like the browser to go to the next page. The thing is, such page is only accessible with an auth header. Methods such as `document.location.href = "http://nextpage"` don't let me set the authorization header, like `Authorization = Bearer 1234567890`.

The code that runs when the user clicks on the "Login" button is:

```
var json = {
  grant_type: "password",
  client_id: "myClient",
  username: email, // <--- comes from a form
  password: password, // <--- comes from a form
  client_secret: "mySecret"
};

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:9000/auth/token/grant",
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(json),
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) {
    localStorage.authToken = data.access_token;
    localStorage.refreshToken = data.refresh_token;

    // Here I would like to move the browser to the next page
    document.location.href = "http://localhost:9000/nextPage";

  }.bind(this),
  error: function (xhr, status, err) {
    console.error("login request error: ", status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
});
```

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: The server has to provide the headers. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405536/how-to-open-a-url-using-javascript-and-set-custom-http-headers-to-the-request). You could store it in the server-side session and provide it that way.

Comment: Thanks @MikeC for your comment. The fact that I want to move to a page on the same domain could maybe make a difference from the other question?