# What would be the best way to change the URL and load a new page with an AJAX get response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

The reason I'm doing this with an AJAX request is because I need to make some custom header for an authentication token, as a simple redirect would have worked otherwise.

```
var config = {headers:  {
        "jwtToken" : sessionStorage.getItem('jwtToken')
    }
};

var successCallback = function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    window.document.write(response.data);
};

var errorCallback = function(response) {
    $location.path('/error');
    console.log(response);
    console.error('/app/graphs GET failed');
};
```

Right now the response is getting written to the document but the URL does not change to what I need it to. Also, I'm not entirely sure if this is a good way to do it.

Essentially my question is asking for the proper way to use an AJAX request to load an entire page while changing the URL to the one the AJAX get request was sent to.

Comment: Learn to use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Example_1_Navigate_to_a_new_page).

Comment: unfortunately you cannot set custom headers with window.location, otherwise I would have used it as I specified in my question :)

Comment: Sorry, missed the custom headers part. I believe this question has been asked before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a url using javascript and set custom HTTP headers to the request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405536/how-to-open-a-url-using-javascript-and-set-custom-http-headers-to-the-request)

Comment: So, yes, in theory your XHR solution can work, but it's going to have side effects that make changing the url kindof pointless. Usually the idea behind changing the url is so that the page can be bookmarked, reloaded, or navigated to with forward/back buttons without breaking it. In this case, reloading or bookmarking would result in a broken page unless you repeated the steps that generated it. Do the work server-side instead and go back to a normal redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load a new url in the browser, you can use:

```
var url = "http://example.com/?jwtToken=" + sessionStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
window.location.assign(url);
```

This would send your header as a get parameter, which you may be able to use in lieu of a header, after adjusting the server side script.